# How to understand closure parameters

Tags: rust

I am a beginner in Rust. I tried to write a **linked list** for practice.

Some sturct code:

```rust
type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

pub struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
}

struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}
```

Peek function for List:

### error code:

```rust
pub fn peek(&self) -> Option<&T> {
    self.head.map(|ref node| {
        &node.elem
    })
}
```

The Rust compiler return: `cannot return value referencing function parameter`.

### The following code is ok:

```rust
pub fn peek(&self) -> Option<&T> {
    self.head.as_ref().map(|node| {
        &node.elem
    })
}
```

### So I guess,

The error code is actually an abbreviation of the following code:

```rust
self.head.map(|node| {
      let ref ref_node = node;
      &ref_node.elem
})
```

Is my guess correct?

More, is there a similar abbreviation in Rust? Or abbreviation rules.

Comment: What do you mean by "is there a similar abbreviation in Rust? Or abbreviation rules."?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I mean, if `|ref node|` is equal to `|node|{let ref node = node}` .Then,  in the map method of option, the input type is determined, and this modification only simplifies the code, not the closure parameters.  such as, `option.map(|mut node|)`. For closures, the input type is still `node`, not `mut node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error “cannot return value referencing function parameter” is sort of a red herring here; it has nothing to do with the fundamental problem, but just happened to be listed first. If you compile the code

```rust
type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

pub struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
}

struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn peek(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        self.head.map(|ref node| &node.elem)
    }
}
```

then you will get two errors, the second of which is the reason this code doesn't work and you needed `.as_ref()`:

```rust
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.head` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/lib.rs:14:9
   |
14 |         self.head.map(|ref node| &node.elem)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.head` has type `Option<Box<Node<T>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content
   |
14 |         self.head.as_ref().map(|ref node| &node.elem)
   |                  +++++++++
```

This error is the one from the root cause; [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) *consumes its input `Option`*, which is not what we want to do here. `Option::as_ref` solves this by taking an `&Option<T>` (here, by implicit auto-reference turning `self.head` into `&self.head`) and returning a newly created `Option<&T>`, which can then be consumed by `Option::map`.

But, I understand that you want to know how the erroneous code produced the “cannot return…” error. Here's how:

1. We know that `self.head` is an `Option<Box<Node<T>>>`.
2. Calling `Option::map()` on that type means it expects a function `FnOnce(Box<Node<T>>) -> &T`.
3. That is, the closure is acting as a function which is given *ownership* of a `Box<Node<T>>`. So, within the closure, `node` is a local variable that owns the `Box`.
4. The body of the closure then attempts to return a reference to a field of the `Node` inside that box, which is an error E0515 since the box is owned by a local variable and is going to be dropped at the end of the function.

Your `ref` modifier does not change things, because whether a value is moved into a function is determined by the function's parameter types, not by what kind of pattern/binding the function body uses.

> The error code is actually an abbreviation of the following code:
>
> ```
> self.head.map(|node| {
>       let ref ref_node = node;
>       &ref_node.elem
> })
> ```
>
> Is my guess correct?

Yes and no. You *can* expand the code that way. But that's not the “real” code; it's rather that introducing the separate ordinary variable `node` before a more complex pattern is always valid, for function parameters. It's not something that the compiler does anyway; it's adding trivial code, in the same way that multiplying by 1 doesn't change a number. But, the fact that you *can* do this without changing the program is a consequence of the fact that function parameters are moved in regardless of what the function itself writes in its parameter patterns.

However, it wouldn't be possible to make your original code work by changing Rust function parameters to work that way. The function which is causing the problem is `Option::map()` applied to a borrowed struct field; that would always fail regardless of what the function passed to `map()` does, because `Option::map()` always consumes the `Option` given to it.